# $_POST is not working on second page

Tags: php, mysql, post

**- FIXED -**

When i submit form, the row i want to edit in table is forcing 0 instead of setting 0 or 1 (when i switch). It means that table (row) is somehow getting value 0.

This is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo BASE_URL?>process.php?task=edit_notify" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="material-switch pull-left">
            <p><span class="control-label" style="color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.6); cursor: default;"><?php echo ADMIN_NOTIFY; ?></span></p>
            <input id="allow_reg_msg" name="allow_reg_msg" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($row['allow_reg_msg'] == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />
            <label for="allow_reg_msg" class="label-primary"></label>
        </div>
    </div></br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn_"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo EDIT; ?></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When i submit, it should send value to process.php page, here is the "process.php?task=edit_notify":

```
if(isset($_GET['task']) && $_GET['task'] == "edit_notify"){
    if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) Redirect::to('index');
    if(!$user->hasPermission('admin')) Redirect::to('index');
    $allow_reg_msg = $_POST['allow_reg_msg'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `settings` SET 
        `allow_reg_msg` = :allow_reg_msg
    WHERE `id` = 1";
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ":allow_reg_msg" => $allow_reg_msg
    ));
    Session::flash('edit_site_success', SUCCESS_UPDATE);
    Redirect::to('admin/index.php?page=edit_site');
}
```

And here are few images from my database:
[image 1](https://image.prntscr.com/image/aKDeTcqeQVWlP7akjSb75g.png),
[image 2](https://image.prntscr.com/image/IzQGrSilQaap7splEtf9xw.png)

Comment: can you show what you get for: `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @Jeff I get "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

I found solution! It was in my `define('BASE_URL', 'https://monkstudio.biz/');`

Because i have in .htaccess my website link with "www", here in script it was not set, now i put `define('BASE_URL', 'https://www.monkstudio.biz/');` and it's working fine!

I'm so proud i found this by myself.